# Most efficient way to determine if a numpy masked array contains any non-masked values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to perform a complicated computation on a masked array only if it contains any (or, ideally, at least X) non-masked values.  Is there a way to do that efficiently without iterating through the array and checking each value?

Comment: Maybe use the all() method to determine if there is at least one non-masked values in the array?  i.e. if not my_array.all(): do calculation

Comment: Not quite; I'll update my answer with something close to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `count()` method tells you how many non-masked elements there are:

```
In [6]: m = np.ma.masked_array([1, 2, 3, 4], mask=[False, False, True, False])

In [7]: m
Out[7]: 
masked_array(data = [1 2 -- 4],
             mask = [False False  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [8]: m.count()
Out[8]: 3
```

If all you want to know is whether or not there are *any* non-masked elements, you can use the `all()` method of the `mask` attribute.  The `mask` attrbute is a boolean array that is True at each masked element.

Here's the mask for `m`:

```
In [16]: m.mask
Out[16]: array([False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Does `m` have any non-masked elements?

```
In [18]: not m.mask.all()
Out[18]: True
```

The elements of `b` are all masked:

```
In [23]: b = np.ma.masked_array([1, 2, 3, 4], mask=[True, True, True, True])
In [24]: b
Out[24]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -- -- --],
             mask = [ True  True  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Any non-masked elements in `b`?

```
In [26]: not b.mask.all()
Out[26]: False
```

Your question was about the most efficient way to do this, so let's compare the timing on a bigger array.

First create a random array with 1000 elements.

```
In [72]: x = np.random.randint(0,3,size=1000)
```

Create a masked array in which the zeros of `x` are masked.

```
In [73]: mx = np.ma.masked_array(x, mask=x==0)

In [74]: mx.count()
Out[74]: 680
```

Timing comparison:

```
In [75]: %timeit mx.count()
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.4 us per loop

In [76]: %timeit not mx.mask.all()
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.37 us per loop
```

So, for this array, `not mx.mask.all()` is about three times faster than `mx.count()`.

Comment: Updated to include the use of the `all()` method of the `mask` attribute and a timing comparison.

Comment: Warren this really is a very well put together response/answer, quite helpful and informative.  Thanks!